# Django 1.4 SimpleListFilter 'selected' option issue

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have written a SimpleListFilter, here is the code:
http://dpaste.com/639578/

It displays in the admin list properly, but i am having an issue, The selected option does not get highlighted in the custom filter. Only 'All' highlights but not the custom options. Here is the screenshot to illustrate that:

[image: http://imgur.com/IyrYk]

---

If anybody interested in this, here is the follow up:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17091

Comment: Could it be because you are not actually doing any filtering on your queryset? Cant test at the moment.

Comment: 1.4? The latest release I see is 1.3.1. (I don't know what version the development trunk is, though).

Comment: offtopic: how did you organize filter choices like dropdowns in admin?

Comment: I'd also like to see your code on how you implemented those drop down menus.

Answer (score 2):

For this reason I implemented a 'choices' function:

```
def choices(self, cl):
    lookup_choices = [('',_('All'))] + self.lookup_choices
    for lookup, title in lookup_choices:
        yield {
            'selected': self.value() == str(lookup),
            'query_string': cl.get_query_string({self.parameter_name: lookup,}, []),
            'display': title,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Offtopic: re the drop down menus, I was also interested. A quick search shows that there is no built in ability to do this, but there are a couple of easy solutions: DIY or use products like Grappelli or FeinCMS.